# Upper bound for the product of all singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, upper-lower-bounds, singular-values

Denote $ C=OPQ^T $, where $O,P,Q$ are all real matrices with sizes $ D^2 \times n $, $ n \times n $ and $ d^2 \times n $ respectively. Assume $ d < D $.

Moreover, $P$ is diagonal, and the sum of its entries is $1$; the first rows of $O,Q$ are all $1$-s; all the columns of $O$ have norm $ \sqrt{D} $, and all the columns of $Q$ have norm $ \sqrt{d} $.

Given these constraints, how can one find an upper bound for the product of all the singular values of $C$ - i.e., $ \sqrt{\det \left( C^T C \right)} $?

**Edit:** I seek an upper bound independent of $n$. I.e., we may freely choose the value of $n$ yielding the maximal determinant.

Moreover, I have a hypothesis for the tight upper bound: I think it is obtained for $ n=d^2 $, $ P = \frac{1}{d^2} 1 $ ($P$ is a scalar matrix), and $O,Q$ are matrices whose columns form $d^2$ *equiangular lines* in $\mathbb{R}^{D^2}, \mathbb{R}^{d^2}$ respectively.

For example, for $d=2,D=3$, I believe the upper bound is obtained for $n=d^2$ and the following matrices:
\begin{equation}
O = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{9} & \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9} & \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & -\frac{7\sqrt{6}}{18} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}}{18} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}}{18} \\
0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} & \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
P = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4}
\end{bmatrix}, Q = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
0 & \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} & -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{bmatrix} .
\end{equation}
Note the relation to tetrahedrons. Also, dividing the first row of $Q$ by $ \sqrt{d+1} = \sqrt{3} $ makes it a scalar times orthogonal, where the scalar is $ \frac{d}{\sqrt{d+1}} $.

I am not certain about the validity of this hypothesis, and even less certain about how to prove it.

Comment: Intuition suggests $\left(\frac{\sqrt{Dd}}{n}\right)^{n/2}$. Would that bound be useful?

Comment: Are the columns of $O$ mutually orthogonal? What about the columns of $Q$?

Comment: @broncoAbierto please see my edit. The bound should be independent of $n$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom not necessarily, but they may be; the question is, do mutually orthogonal columns yield the maximal value? I edited the question to include my hypothesis regarding which matrices obtain the maximum.